# MySQL- Possible to search and replace based on conditional?

Tags: mysql

In my WP database, I want to find all occurrences of www.example.com and remove the .htm extension, but ONLY if it's specifically www.example.com

I'm trying to change all instances of www.example.com/page.htm to www.example.com/page

basically I want to perform:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '.htm','') WHERE (string that has .htm also includes www.example.com);
```

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE post_content LIKE 'www.example.com%'
```